# where clause not displaying data

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to display data based on wether data in a field is new. instead of showing only the data that is new it is showing all data. can someone point out my error. many thanks

```
<?php
include("../../js/JSON.php");
$json = new Services_JSON();
// Connect to MySQL database
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db(sample);
$page = 1; // The current page
$sortname = 'id'; // Sort column
$sortorder = 'asc'; // Sort order
$qtype = ''; // Search column
$query = ''; // Search string
$new = 1;
// Get posted data
if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['page']);
}
if (isset($_POST['sortname'])) {
$sortname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sortname']);
}
if (isset($_POST['sortorder'])) {
$sortorder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sortorder']);
}
if (isset($_POST['qtype'])) {
$qtype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qtype']);
}
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']);
}
if (isset($_POST['rp'])) {
$rp = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rp']);
}
// Setup sort and search SQL using posted data
$sortSql = "order by $sortname $sortorder";
$searchSql = ($qtype != '' && $query != '') ? "where ".$qtype." LIKE '%".$query."%' AND new = 1" : '';
// Get total count of records
$sql = "select count(*)
from act
$searchSql";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];
// Setup paging SQL
$pageStart = ($page -1)*$rp;
$limitSql = "limit $pageStart, $rp";
// Return JSON data
$data = array();
$data['page'] = $page;
$data['total'] = $total;
$data['rows'] = array();
$sql = "select *
from act
$searchSql 
$sortSql
$limitSql";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
$data['rows'][] = array(
'id' => $row['id'],
'cell' => array($row['id'], $row['slot'], $row['service'], $row['activity'], $row['department'], $row['company'], $row['address'], $row['user'], $row['item'], $row['filebox'], date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['date'])), $row['quantity'], $row['type'], $row['new'])
);
}
echo $json->encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Are all records marked with `new = 1`? If not, you should look in a sql profiler or something to see the actual query being executed.  Post that here.

Comment: What value are you posting to $qtype? Your where clause needs to say something about new records.

Comment: As an aside, you don't have to run to run a `SELECT COUNT(*)`. Check out `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Comment: is this not correct in the where clause? AND new = 1". this is what firebug says:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where company LIKE '%demo%'' at line 3

Comment: lucas. all records are either 0 or 1. if they are new then they = 1 and 0 for read.

Answer (score 4):

- You should debug SQL by looking at the SQL query, not at the PHP code that produces the SQL query.  If you `echo $sql` and look at it, you'll probably see any syntax errors much more easily.

You can also copy & paste that SQL and try to execute it in the MySQL command tool, and see what happens, whether it gives the result you want, you can profile it or use EXPLAIN, etc.

- You're using `mysql_real_escape_string()` for integers, column names, and SQL keywords (`ASC`, `DESC`).  That escape function is for escaping *only* string literals or date literals.  It's useless for escaping unquoted integers, column names, SQL keywords, or any other SQL syntax.

For integers, use `(int)` to typecast inputs to an integer.

For column names or SQL keywords, use a whitelist map -- see example in my presentation http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies

- You're not testing for error statuses returned by any of your functions.  Most functions in ext/mysql return `false` if some error occurs.  You should check for that after *every* call to a mysql function, and report errors if they occur.
- You're selecting a database using a constant name `sample` instead of a quoted string `"sample"`.  This might be intentional on your part, I'm just noting it.
- Also, this is not related to your errors, but you should really [upgrade to PHP 5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php).  PHP 4 has been end-of-lifed for over two years now.

Answer (score 0):

after looking at the code again and all the suggestions i think i should be using an AND clause and not WHERE. for example the code 
$searchSql = ($qtype != '' && $query != '') ? "where ".$qtype." LIKE '%".$query."%' AND new = 1" : ''; 
this is the WHERE clause? which basically translates to:

$sql = "select *
from act
$searchSql
$sortSql
$limitSql"; <- original code

$sql = "select *
from act
WHERE company LIKE '%demo%' AND new = 1
$sortSql
$limitSql";<-updated code

am i on the right track?

Comment: I can't see how this helps, but what happens when you try it?